# How to enter multiple contacts in one custom object?

Tags: custom-object, relationships

I created a custom Object "Visit Reports" and would like to be able to pick all participants from the Standard object Contacts.
I have entered several "Participant 1, 2, 3,..." lookup fields to Contact.

In Contacts I get a related list to each Participant Field.

What do I have to change to get in the Object Customer just one related list, showing all "Visit Reports" were the contact is named in one of the participant fields?

Or is there different solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Junction Object. It will solve your problem.
Create a Junction between contact and Visit Reports. And then create Many to Many relationship. In this way you have only one related list with multiple Contacts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What do I have to put in the Junction Object?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What do I have to put in the Junction Object? I have in "VISIT REPORTS" following Fields: Participant 1, Participant 2, Participant 3, Participant 4   //  What fields do I Need in CONTACTS and what fields do I need in CONTACT JUNCTION?

Comment: In Junction create two Master Detail one with contact and second with Visit Reports. Example: Now create 4 records, select same Visit Reports record and 4 diff contact record or Vice-versa. In this way you can create multi relationship.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I am looking for.  Is there the possibility to Name the related list differently in both Objects e.g. in Contacts --> Visit Reports & in Visit Reports --> Meeting Attendees ?

Comment: @Hans Yes when you create relationship field then salesforce give you option to change the name of related list. And it solve your problem then mark this as answer so it will help others.